# How to generate folium heatmap from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, folium

I'm currently trying to generate a heatmap in Leaflet.js using Folium in Python 2.7. I think I might be getting the long/lat syntax incorrectly for it to be rendered properly.

The csv file have the following layout: name,longitude,latitude

Example:

```
incident1,-1.44986889,-48.48197937
incident2,-1.37189305,-48.44008189
```

The code I've written looks like this:

```
import folium
import csv
from folium import plugins

heatmap_map = folium.Map(location=[51.67109, -1.28278], zoom_start=2)

with open('/tmp/geolocation.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data = ([row[1]], [row[2]])
        hm = plugins.HeatMap(data)
        heatmap_map.add_children(hm)
f.close()

heatmap_map.save("/tmp/heatmap.html")
```

The program runs, saves the file but I cannot see any heatmaps when I load it in my browser. I have verified that I can create location markers so it is loading the maps as it should.

I'm afraid that I don't know enough about Leaflet.js to troubleshoot the code in the html file that is generated.

Can anyone please give me a hand here and show what might be wrong in the data variable or possibly a better way of iterating through my csv file to generate the necessary heatmaps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I believe your problem is in the formatting of the data points.  The following should work:

```
with open('/tmp/geolocation.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [[row[1], row[2]] for row in reader]
        
hm = plugins.HeatMap(data)
heatmap_map.add_child(hm)
```

Comment: That is the perfect answer. I was trying to achieve the same using a pandas data frame. Thank you.